# Google Sheet Query - Select statement working unexpectedly

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a strange issue which has unknowingly arisen where my google sheet query is working unexpectedly.
I have a master sheet which holds information to do with class times and students etc which is then divided into subsheets for different days and locations using querys selecting from the master sheet.
The cell in the subsheet with the query however is pulling all the information from the sheet into the respective row. The below rows are populated correctly based on the query.
One of my querys in the subsheet is as below:

=QUERY(Master!A:Y,"Select * where A <> '' and J = 'Balwyn' and L = '4-5 Hip Hop MINI' AND K ='Monday' ")

Based on the above query the expected result is to populate the sheet with all students who elected to be in the 4-5 Hip Hop Class at Balwyn on mondays. As you can see in the picture below it does this correctly for the rows beneath the row which has the cell that contains the query, but in that row it is pulling all the Student Last names , i've selected colunm B here to highlight that it has all the last names from everyone in the master sheet in that cell. This is the same for each column on that row.
[image]
Sorry i cant share view of sheet as it holds client info.

Comment: Come to the realization that this actually isn't an issue as it is getting the data and populating the rows as it should beneath it. I'll just blank out that row with all the data to white text to avoid confusion but was thinking it would populate the first row that has the query as normal also

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (always) using the headers argument in query()

```
=QUERY(Master!A:Y,"Select * where A <> '' and J = 'Balwyn' and L = '4-5 Hip Hop MINI' AND K ='Monday' ", 1)
```

(If you don't want to retrieve the header row, change 1 to 0).

See if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the response - I just found a fix for me which i posted

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a data validation issue. Read on google docs that the QUERY function can only accept one data type per column which i had some mix of numerical and alpha in some cells of the same column which caused errors and this behaviour. I selected the whole sheet and formatted it to be 'Plain Text' via the format tab and this fixed my issues.